# VS Setup Project- Custom Action to capture user defined path during installation

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio

I have created a window application in VS 2015.I am trying to capture the folder path input by the user during installation. I have added the installer class to provide access rights on the installation folder. Also i have added the screen to browse application's path during installation. Now i am trying to add a folder path where it will keep the files generated by my application. Currently it is saving in the root folder of the application but i want to allow user to save it in desired location. I have tried using Text Boxes but unable to find a way to put a browse button to locate the path and save it in the app config file. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to use is `FolderBrowserDialog` class. Create a simple button on the form and double click it
to add an event handler for the click event. In this event handler, do the following:

```
FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if (folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // If the user selects a path and clicks OK, display the path in the
    // text box and save it in a variable for later use
    textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
    applicationFilesPath = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
}
```

Simply rename objects `textBox1` and `applicationFilesPath` with the names you are using and you are done.